# Is sodomy or fellatio illegal in India?

Tags: india, indian-penal-code, sexual-offences

[This](https://timesofindia.indiatimes.com/blogs/legally-speaking/unnatural-offences-decrypting-the-phrase-against-the-order-of-nature/) article suggests that any penetration by a male other than vaginal is proscribed as against the order of nature.

Is that right in 2023?

[This](https://antigaylaws.org/commonwealth/) suggests no.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[IPC 377](https://www.indiacode.nic.in/show-data?actid=AC_CEN_5_23_00037_186045_1523266765688&orderno=434) was largely rendered irrelevant by the ruling of [Navtej Singh Johar vs Union Of India](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fe/Section_377_-_Supreme_Court_of_India_-_WP%28C%29_NO._76_OF_2016_Judgement_06-Sep-2018.pdf) (2018),

> i. In view of the aforesaid findings, it is declared that insofar as
> Section 377 criminalises consensual sexual acts of adults (i.e.
> persons above the age of 18 years who are competent to consent) in
> private, is violative of Articles 14, 15, 19, and 21 of the
> Constitution. It is, however, clarified that such consent must be free
> consent, which is completely voluntary in nature, and devoid of any
> duress or coercion.
>
> ii. The declaration of the aforesaid reading down of Section 377 shall
> not, however, lead to the reopening of any concluded prosecutions, but
> can certainly be relied upon in all pending matters whether they are
> at the trial, appellate, or revisional stages.
>
> iii. The provisions of Section 377 will continue to govern
> non-consensual sexual acts against adults, all acts of carnal
> intercou[r]se against minors, and acts of beastiality.

The earlier law would have precluded any intercourse other than male-female vaginal intercourse, but that law has been deemed unconstitutional.